# Django: unable to display iunformation using a TemplateView Class Based view

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm using a Class Based view (TemplateView) to display some information from a User and a UserProfile model (onetoone between User and UserProfile) and this is working as expected.
I decided to use the same TemplateView to display some other data from 2 models and I don't understand why I cannot retrieve and display information.
I suspect this is because one of the models (UserSubscription) has 2 fks, one to User model, and another one to "Subscription" model.
I've tried to use related_name in the fks but not sure I'm using it correctly.
Hereunder the code:

models.py

```
class UserSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name= 'tousers', related_query_name='touser', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey("Subscription", related_name = 'tosubscriptions', related_query_name='tosubscription',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Created Date")
    subs_status = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Subscription Status")
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Expiry Date")
    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User Subscription"
        verbose_name_plural = "User Subscriptions"

    def __str__(self):
        return 'User: ' + str(self.user) + ' ' + 'PK: ' + str(self.pk) + ' Subscription :' + str(self.subscription) + ' ' + 'Expiring the : ' +  str(self.expiry_date)

class Subscription(models.Model):
    plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Subscription Plan Name")    
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Subscription Plan Description")   
    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Subscription Plan Price")   
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Subscription Plan Start Date")
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Subscription Plan End Date")   
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)         

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Subscription"
        verbose_name_plural = "Subscriptions"       

    def __str__(self):
        return self.plan_name
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView, ListView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import *
from .forms import *


class MyProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'myprofile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(MyProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['User'] = User.objects.all()
         context['UserProfile'] = UserProfile.objects.all()
         context['subscription'] = Subscription.objects.all()
         context['usersubscription'] = UserSubscription.objects.all()
         return context
```

myprofile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
My Profile
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Username: {{user.username}}</p>
<p>First Name: {{user.first_name}}</p>
<p>Last Name: {{user.last_name}}</p>
<p>Birth Date: {{user.userprofile.birth_date}}</p>
<p>Email: {{user.email}}</p>
<p>Language: {{user.userprofile.language}}</p>
<p>Address: {{user.userprofile.address}}</p>
<p>Postal Code: {{user.userprofile.postal_code}}</p>
<p>Country: {{user.userprofile.country}}</p>
<form action ='{% url "updatemyprofile" %}'>
<button type="submit">Update My Profile</button>
</form>
<hr>
<p>My Current Plan:{{usersubscription.subscription.plan_name}}</p>
<p>Start Date: {{usersubscription.created_date}}</p>
<p>End Date: {{usersubscription.expiry_date}}</p>
<p>Renew:</p>
<hr>

{% endblock  %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views as gecviews

urlpatterns = [
    path('myprofile/', gecviews.MyProfileView.as_view(), name='myprofile'), 
    path('updatemyprofile/', gecviews.profileUpdate, name='updatemyprofile'),
```

result:

Username: foo

First Name: foo

Last Name: bar

Birth Date: Feb. 2, 2020

Email: foo@bar.com

Language: EN

Address: foobar avenue

Postal Code: 1000

Country: US

My Current Plan:

Start Date:

End Date:

Renew:

Comment: You're doing `.objects.all()` with each model which returns a queryset (multiple objects) and not single objects. Therefore, in your template you'd have to iterate over the queryset in order to display your data.

Answer (score 0):

This is because what you have in context['usersubscription'] is a queryset.

try this in your view:

```
context['usersubscription'] = UserSubscription.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

or you can change these in your template:

```
<p>My Current Plan:{{request.user.user_subscription.subscription.plan_name}}</p>
<p>Start Date: {{request.user.usersubscription.subscription.created}}</p>
<p>End Date: {{request.user.usersubscription.subscription.expiry_date}}</p>
```

**EDIT**

```
{% with request.user.tousers|first as t %}
t.subscription.expiry_date
{% end with %}
```

Comment: I've done the followingin my view: UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=self.request.user) and I  get nothing in return in my template, although I'm sure the user "foo" has a "1 year" subscription. I've tried also the second method (on template only) and same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use self.request. Just request.

Comment: if I do `UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=request.user)` i get an error `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`. since this is a class based view i need to use `self.request.user`. this way i don't get the error described. That being said, i still cannot get the subscription of this user.

Comment: On the template you can try to loop through the user subscriptions because it is a foreign key which means many to one relationship. See edit

Comment: Thanks for the help. Solved by adding a .last() (to get the last subscription for a specific user). `UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)` was returning a queryset, so perhaps i could indeed loop to get the same result

Comment: If users can't have multiple plans, try using the OneToOneField.

Answer (score 0):

I was ale to solve this by doing a .last() as following:
`UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).last()`

result:

My Current Plan:1 Year

Start Date: March 9, 2021, 7:49 p.m.

End Date: March 9, 2021, 7:49 p.m.

Renew my Subscription

My Bills:

Bill 1: 50.0 €